# Notation: function codomain is a set of functions

Tags: functions

I know that the following notation works:
$f:A \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(B,C)$, where $\mathcal{F}(B,C)=\{g|g:B \rightarrow C\}$.

But does the following notation make sense? I mean, is it correct to write:
$f: A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$?

Comment: Short answer: no. Almost, if you replace the parentheses with curly braces. But don't. Stick with the original notation.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to know if the second one was also common. From your response I denote that it is not. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please either delete the question or answer it for yourself (that's OK) so it doesn't stay on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Short answer: no. Almost, if you replace the parentheses with curly braces. But don't. Stick with the original notation.

Thanks, Ethan Bolker!